# shell linux - LDAPS connection not possible V3

Tags: linux, shell, ldap

Hello I try a connection with shell linux and powershell but nothing works

```
#!/bin/bash

# Paramètres de connexion LDAPS
LDAP_SERVER="ldap2.xxxx.fr" # URL du serveur LDAPS
LDAP_PORT=636 # Port LDAPS par défaut

# Informations d'identification
USERNAME="cn=gpuc-operator,ou=admin,dc=xxxx,dc=fr"
PASSWORD="xxxx"

# Base de recherche
BASE_DN="ou=people,dc=xxxx,dc=fr"

# Test de la connexion LDAPS
if ldapsearch -H "ldaps://$LDAP_SERVER:$LDAP_PORT" -D "$USERNAME" -w "$PASSWORD" -b "$BASE_DN" -s base -ZZ "(objectclass=*)" 2>/dev/null; then
            echo "La connexion LDAPS a réussi."
    else
                echo "La connexion LDAPS a échoué. Vérifiez les informations d'identification ou la configuration du serveur."
        fi
```

I try this code and connection is failed

With LDAPADMIN tool in windows is working, the linux should work too

[image]

636 is open in this linux for the ldap
maybe have you an idea?
Thx for help

Comment: What result do you get if you test the `ldapsearch` command on its own? Without redirecting `stderr` btw.